# how to do python DNS lookup in the list of domain in a file

Tags: python, dns

```
import dns.resolver

with open('fname.txt') as f:
    read_data = f.read().strip("\n")

for aline in read_data:
    nameservers = dns.resolver.query(read_data, 'NS')
    for data in nameservers:
        print (data)

f.close()
```

I have a list of domain on fname.txt and I would like to do NS lookup on every domain on it. can anyone please help me to read on the domain on my file and then output the result of each domain that has the same ns lookup result.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Instead of reading all at once, you can simply iterate over the opened file object, reading line by line (just remember to strip `\n`). Also, you don't need to close the file when using a context manager (`with`), since it does that for you.

```
import dns.resolver

with open('fname.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        domain = line.strip()
        nameservers = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'NS')
        for data in nameservers:
            print(data)
```

Comment: I see, but how do I skip if there is an error when the script encounter a domain that is no longer has a NS record?

Comment: Wrap the querying with `try`/`except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN` block.

Comment: that I don't know how to use, I am still learning python, will look on it on google.

Comment: Ok, I was able to use try/except block.

Comment: if may I ask @randomir

                if data == 'ns1.yahoo.com.' and data == 'ns2.yahoo.com.':
                    print (data, domain)

is this statement correct? I am trying to find which domain will have the same NS and then print it out.

Comment: Why don't you try it? That's the beauty of Python, easy experimenting. The more you play with it, the better you'll understand and learn. But yes, your statement seems correct.

Comment: yeah, i did tried it, but it doesn't do, what I want it to do. seems that with this I am receiving two arguments ns1 and ns2, seems that the script doesnt see the 2nd arguments receive so it end up nothing.

            for data in nameservers:
                #if (nameservers == 'ns1.yahoo.com') or (nameservers == 'ns2.yahoo.com'):
                print (data, domain)
                with open('something.txt', 'a+') as fin:
                    fin.write(data, domain)


I am also trying to write it on a file but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. Here people post specific problems they have, together with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which enables us to reproduce that problem and help them. After people get their answer, they [upvote and accept one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as a way of thanking and promoting good content. If you have a follow-up question, you should write a new question, avoiding the continued discussion in comments,as it's hard to follow for the next visitor that comes here.